# mattlab: remove SUB char from end of text file

Tags: matlab, text, import

I import text in matlab using `importdata`

```
A = importdata(logFile, '\t', 1);
```

this works fine, unless the "SUB" char is at the end of the file.[image]

In this case I get the error

> Error in
>   matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)uiProjekt('menuEvalAllData_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Caused by:
>       Error using vertcat
>       Dimensions of matrices being
>       concatenated are not
>       consistent.

My question is: how can I work around this error?
The simplest idea would be to remove the char from the file before. But how would I remove a single char from a large text file efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strrep` to replace the `SUB` char. `strrep` is pretty efficient and should be fast even with large files.

The decimal value of the `SUB` char in ASCII is 26.

Here's an example code that removes the `SUB` char from an input file `input.txt`:

```
% Open files:
inputID  = fopen('input.txt','r');
outputID  = fopen('output.txt','w');

file_data=fread(inputID,'*char')'; % Read all data from input file
file_data_fixed = strrep(file_data,char(26),''); % Find and replace the SUB char with blank
fprintf(outputID,'%s',file_data_fixed); % Print all data (without SUB) to output file

% Close files:
fclose(inputID);
fclose(outputID);
```

Comment: I used something similar, but only check the end of the input, since the SUB is very likely at the end.